# Multiseat software differences

Tags: windows-8, windows-multipoint-server

I am in the position of creating a multiseat configuration. My requirement is something which works on win8. I have narrowed my solutions down to Aster V7 from www.ibik.ru . As far as my research went, this is the only software good enough which works on windows 8.1
The other day I found out about Microsoft Multipoint Server 2012 and now I am confused. Is this operating system doing the same thing as the Aster software? if yes, what are the differences? if no, what are the differences?

Comment: could please someone add new tags in the post? multipoint server 2012

Answer (score 1):

Aster works for gaming. Multi-point feels more like a terminal access but directly connected to the video card. Aster you will just install. Multi-point you will need to load that as your operating system it's  not an add on.